# How to pull one tvalue from Tuple if key matches

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, tuples

In my program I joined two IEnumerables and converted them to a dictionary like so:

```
//list1 is a list of all contracts, list2 is a list of special contracts
var list1 = //List of objects
Var list2 = //List of objects 
var combined = List1.Join(list2, c=> s.contractNumber, dto => dto.contract, (s, dto) => dto)
.ToDictonary( x => x.Contract, y => y.Date);

var final = list1.Select(contractNumber =>{
var number = contract.ContractNumber;
contract.Date = combined.ContainsKey(number) ? combined[number] : string.Empty;
}
```

Short version is this: We used list1 to populate a table we are displaying on the front end, but the business requested changes that required displaying information from a separate API call. List1 did not have the date field included but list2 does. So we added the property to list1, and then use a dictionary to populate the property based on the keyvalue pair.

They have made another request to show another field from list2 on the frontend so I thought to use a tuple like so:

```
.ToDictionary(x=>x.Contract, y => Tuple.Create(y.Date, y.Type));
```

But I am having difficulties updating the code here:

```
contract.Date = combined.ContainsKey(number) ? combined[number] : string.Empty; //It breaks due to converting tuple<string, string> to string
```

Whats the best way to populate a field using one of the values from the tuple based on the key?

Comment: Try null instead of string.Empty

Comment: The issue would be when the condition is true, the combined[number] portion. ITs wanting to pull the value associated with that key, but now there are two values so it is confused. I need it to only use Value1

Comment: Use : combined.Item2

Comment: combined[number].Item2 works. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your code. For example the line `var final = list1.Select(contractNumber =>{` declares a lambda with an argument `contractNumber` that is not used anywhere. After that a variable `contract` appears that is not declared anywhere. Also I am not sure if the properties `s.contractNumber` and `contract.ContractNumber` are different, or the same property with a transcription error (starting with `c` instead of `C`).

Comment: Its pseudo code where I slightly modified some of the variable names for business reasons. I only provided what was necessary for understanding the issue and what I was trying to do. The first contractNumber declared in the lambda should just be "contract" though

Comment: This is not pseudo code. This is bad C#. You could modify the variable names for business reasons, and still have valid C# code.

Comment: Its not the code that is written in my program. I'm sorry if I didn't spend much time giving thought to how to rename and alter names to protect business interests, I mistakenly thought it was more important that I articulate the issue I was having, of which you offered no help on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that list1 is a sequence of similar items, let's call them `Contracts`. Every `Contract` has a property `ContractNumber`.

List2 is also a sequence of similar items. Not sure what's in it, but let's call them `ContractDates`. Every `ContractDate` has properties `Contract` and a `Date`.

Oh, I almost forgot: `ContractDate.Contract` is the ContractNumber of the Contract that the ContractDate belongs to. So if ContractDate.Contract equals 14, then this ContractDate belongs to the Contract with number 14.

And finally: the relation is a one-to-zero-or-one: Every Contract has zero or one ContractDate, every ContractDate belongs to exactly one Contract, namely the Contract that the foreign key Contract refers to.

So there might be Contracts that have no ContractDate

It seems, that you want (several properties of) all Contracts, each with the Date of its `ContractDate`. If a Contract has no ContractDate, then you want to use a default value for Date (in your case String.Empty)

You were right, whenever you table of items, where every item has zero or more items from another table, and you want to combine those two tables, you use some kind of join.

> If you want items, each with its one-and-only other item, use **Join**. If you want items each with their zero or more other items, use **GroupJoin**.

So GroupJoin in the following cases:

- Schools with their zero or more Students
- Customers with their zero or more Orders
- Contracts with their zero or more ContractDates (in your case: zero or one)

Use Join if you want it the other way round:

- Students with their one-and-only School they attend
- Orders with the Customer that place the Order
- ContractDates with the Contract that the foreign key refers to.

You have your problem, because you took the wrong direction: instead of Join you should have used [one of the overloads of GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin).

In your case, it is best to use the overload with parameter resultSelector: for every Contract, with its zero or more ContractDates (in your case: zero or one), make one new object:

```
IEnumerable<Contract> contracts = ...
IEnumerable<ContractDate> contractDates = ...

var contractsWithTDates = contracts.GroupJoin(contractDates,

    contract => contract.ContractNumber,      // from every contract take the number
    contractDate => contractDate.Contract,    // from every contractDate take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector: for every Contract, with its zero or more ContractDates
   // make one new object:
   (contract, contractDatesOfThisContract) => new ...);
```

Now what do you want as resulting object:

- I want several parameters of the Contract
- I want the Date of the one-and-only ContractDate, or String.Empty if there is no ContractDate

  const string defaultContractDate = String.Empty;
  var contractsWithTDates = contracts.GroupJoin(contractDates,
  ...

  ```
   (contract, contractDatesOfThisContract) => new
   {
       // Select the zero or more properties of the contract that you want:
       ContractNumber = contract.ContractNumber,
       CustomerId = contract.CustomerId,
       ...

       // Select the properties of the contract dates of this contract that you want
       // if there is one: use the date
       // if there is none: use the defaultContractDate
       // if there is more than one, which you don't expect, use the first contractDate
       Date = contractDatesOfThisContract
              .Select(contractDate => contractDate.Date)
              .FirstOrDefault() ?? defaultContractDate,
   });
  ```

In words: for every Date in contractDatesOfThisContract (of which you expect at utmost one), select property Date. From the resulting sequence of Dates, take the first one, or if there is no first one, return "Default", which in this case is null.

Operator ?? (the null-coalescing operator): If the result of the FirstOrDefault is non-null, use this value, if it is null, use the defaultContractDate.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. You have the general idea of the situation. However the problem wasn't with contract dates. That was the initial request that was provided fairly easily. The problem came when they came back and said oh we need another property displayed also. The quick solution was provided in the comments for my question -- using a tuple works I was just missing the .Item1/.item2 syntax